# psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I have an up and running PostgreSQL database. Now I would like to automate some operations on my database but I have a problem with the password.

I am using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PGPASSWORD="postgres"
sudo -u postgres psql -d pg_ldap -w --no-password -h localhost -p 5432 -t -c "SELECT id FROM radusers WHERE id=1"
```

When I run the bash script I get the following error:

```
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have even tried to configure the .pgpass file in my home directory but to no avail:

```
*:*:*:postgres:postgres
```

I have run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 0600 .pgpass
```

Nevertheless it does not seem that any of the methods works. Does anyone have any idea? Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: Try `sudo su -c psql postgres psql ...` instead.

Comment: The `.pgpass` is in *your* home directory? Not in the `postgres` user's one?

Comment: Yes it is in my home directory, i.e. /home/server2/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sudo` does not retain most environment variables. If you want to specify environment variables to a command run under `sudo`, do so though `sudo`:

```
sudo PGPASSWORD="postgres" -u postgres psql -d pg_ldap -w --no-password -h localhost -p 5432 -t -c "SELECT id FROM radusers WHERE id=1"
```

Whether or not `sudo` permits this will depend on the security policy in force on your site.

I don't recommend this approach as it exposes the password in the command-line history and in the process list. It's much better to use a `.pgpass` file, or preferably set `pg_hba.conf` up for `peer` authentication of `local` connections from user `postgres`.

You can use a `.pgpass` file, but it must be the `.pgpass` of the user you're `sudo`'ing to, not the user you're `sudo`ing *from*; it'd need to be `~postgres/.pgpass` in this case. Think about it: `psql` running as `postgres` doesn't know you ran it via `sudo` from your account, it doesn't know what your user account is, and even if it did it doesn't have read permission as user `postgres` to `~youruser/.pgpass`.

Additionally, `-w` is the same as `--no-password`. There's no point specifying both.

Comment: You could also setup sudo to allow you to use the `-E` option which will preserve your environment (including `PGPASSWORD`). This prevents it showing on the process list.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs if the password for the database is not given.

```
default="postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/DBname"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have even tried to configure the .pgpass file *in my home directory* but to no avail:

You need to create the .pgpass file in the home directory of the account running the **psql** command, i.e. the **postgres** account, not yours!

> psql -d pg_ldap **-w** **--no-password** ...

I think these options might be confusing things as well.

Both mean the same things, specifically "don't *use* a password".

I'd suggest removing these.  psql will acknowledge that a password is required but should detect a correctly-placed .pgpass file and use that instead of *asking* for a password.

And, of course, your postgres account password isn't *really* "postgres", is it?  :-)